# I want to implement lwip server with stm32

Tags: c, server, stm32, lwip

```
    void Tcp_Task(void const * argument)

{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Tcp_Task */

  

  struct netconn *conn, *newconn;

  err_t err, accept_err;

  struct netbuf *buf;

  void *data;

  u16_t len;

  

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    

  LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(argument);

  

    HAL_Delay(1000);

  

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  

  conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);

  

    HAL_Delay(1000);

  

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  

  if (conn!=NULL)

  {

    // netconn_bind(conn, NULL, port 번호)

    err = netconn_bind(conn, NULL, 5001);

    if (err == ERR_OK)

    {

      netconn_listen(conn);

      while (1) 

      {

        accept_err = netconn_accept(conn, &newconn);

    

        if (accept_err == ERR_OK) 

        {

          while (netconn_recv(newconn, &buf) == ERR_OK) 

          {

            do 

            {

              netbuf_data(buf, &data, &len);

              memcpy(receivemsg, data, len);

              

              // 메시지 송신

              netconn_write(newconn, data, msg_len, NETCONN_COPY);

              

            } 

            while (netbuf_next(buf) >= 0);

            

            netbuf_delete(buf);

          }

          netconn_close(newconn);

          netconn_delete(newconn);

        }

       

       osDelay(100);

      }

    }

    else

    {

      netconn_delete(newconn);

    }

  }

 

  

  /* Infinite loop */

    for(;;)

    {

      osDelay(100);

    }

  /* USER CODE END Tcp_Task */

}
```

I want to use the above to implement lwip server with stm32, but if I debug the project, the server implementation works well, but it's not working because I just want to connect the power without removing the ST-Link wire and debugging it

If you see that the LED is blinking, the code seems to work normally, but strangely, it is not connected to the client

I think there's something about conn = netconn_new (NETCONN_TCP) or LWIP_UNUSED_ARG (argument), but if it's a problem here, shouldn't it not be debugged?

The test was well done by implementing the message response, but if it is not debugged, the client connection is not working

Isn't it usually debugged and if you get the desired result without any errors?

Please tell me the solution

Notes Blog :
https://blog.naver.com/eziya76/221867311729

Things set up in cubemx

lwip
[image]

freertos
[image]

eth
[image]

rcc
[image]

Comment: This question is far too long.

Comment: If you try not to debug and just connect the Jeonwooer and the Ethernet wire, it doesn't show why the server isn't working